# selecting value from another table in a case when statement (subquery inside case when) in snowflake

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have written queries to insert data into 2 tables. T1 is basically a temp table with the value that I need to insert into T2. I'm trying to use a subquery within my case when statement to get the value from t1 into t2 when the condition is met. However, I keep getting the error message "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated". The 2 queries below show what I am trying to accomplish.

Q1:

```
insert into t1
select 
      max(filingdate) over (partition by id) as max_filingdate, 
      id,
      value
from sl_table
```

Q2:

```
insert into t2
select 
      id,
      asOfDate,
      filingdate,
      value,
  CASE
     WHEN MAX(AsOfDate) <= c1.FilingDate THEN (Select value 
                                               from t1 
                                               join t2 on t1.id = t2.id)
     ELSE t2.value
     END AS t2_value
from sl_table
*** a bunch of joins and where statements**
group by id, asofdate, filingdate, value
```

I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this. I've already tried using a cte but that returned too many rows for the subquery. I've also tried joining t1 to t2 but then it doesn't grab the values from t1. I would appreciate any help or suggestions for another way to accomplish this. Is there any way to select the value for MAX(FilingDate) OVER (Partition by id) in the query for t2?  Or a way to grab the values from t1 for the corrrect id's?

Comment: the snowflake way is to: in a sub-select/cte build the "other value" for every row, then join to that, and use the case statement to select "normal" value or "extra special alternative" value. This way you are build data processing pipeline (aka how it works) as compared to doing per row querries.

Answer (score 0):

given the join is happening after the group you can ether do it like

```
insert into t2
select 
    a.id,
    a.asOfDate,
    a.filingdate,
    a.value,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.flag THEN t1.value
        ELSE a.value
    END AS t2_value
from (
    select 
          id,
          asOfDate,
          filingdate,
          value,
          MAX(AsOfDate) <= c1.FilingDate as flag
    from sl_table
    *** a bunch of joins and where statements**
    group by id, asofdate, filingdate, value
) as a
join t1 
on t1.id = a.id
```

or you can join `T1` inside the grouping, and then waste CPU/IO folding it up.

Comment: can I ask why you included the any_value function?

Comment: because I was not sure if it was part of the GROUP BY as I wasn't looking too close, but I see it is there..